# Is there a tool that pastes from clipboard one character at a time?

Tags: x11, clipboard, kde4

Is there a tool that pastes from clipboard one character at a time? Something that would simulate a real person typing, like in the movies ;)

Of course I am referring to X applications, preferably KDE, but others will do also.

**UPDATE** - I need to type to GUI applications, not the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

```
xsel | sed 's/./usleep 200000,str &,/g' | xargs -d, xte
```

"xte" is part of xautomation. xclip is another alternative to xsel.

That would work for letters, but probably not many others as that generates key events based on strings.

Comment: This is almost working ... except TAB and new-line characters. I also tried something like this `xsel | pv -q -L 20 | xargs -n1 -I{} xte "str {}"`

Answer (score 0):

You could try a keyboard macro utility like [autokey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/). It's scriptable in python so has access to the X clipboard.